# How to fix import suggestion in next.js and next-auth VS Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I have problem in VS Code. When I type eg. signIn which is function in next-auth I don't get auto import suggestion. What is problem?

My jsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

nextconfig file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

[image: My suggestions]

Suggestions on youtube tutorials:

[image]

I searched on google but I can't find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `baseUrl` to your `compilerOptions` to specify from which folder the import should be suggested, something like (also added some useful settings):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Same situation, not working, I don't have suggestions.